# create this array

Tags: arrays, encryption

i know this sounds silly, but can someone please post the arrays described by rfc2612:

```
Cm = 0x5A827999
Mm = 0x6ED9EBA1
Cr = 19
Mr = 17

for (i=0; i<24; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        Tmj_(i) = Cm
        Cm = (Cm + Mm) mod 2**32
        Trj_(i) = Cr
        Cr = (Cr + Mr) mod 32
    }
}
```

i think im doing is wrong for some reason
i get this for Tr

```
[[10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2],
[10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2],
[10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2],
[10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2],
[10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2],
[10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2],
[10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2],
[10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tr0 = { 19, 27, 3, 11, 19, 27, 3, 11, 19, 27, 3, 11, 19, 27, 3, 11, 19, 27, 3, 11, 19, 27, 3, 11 }
Tr1 = { 4, 12, 20, 28, 4, 12, 20, 28, 4, 12, 20, 28, 4, 12, 20, 28, 4, 12, 20, 28, 4, 12, 20, 28 }
Tr2 = { 21, 29, 5, 13, 21, 29, 5, 13, 21, 29, 5, 13, 21, 29, 5, 13, 21, 29, 5, 13, 21, 29, 5, 13 }
Tr3 = { 6, 14, 22, 30, 6, 14, 22, 30, 6, 14, 22, 30, 6, 14, 22, 30, 6, 14, 22, 30, 6, 14, 22, 30 }
Tr4 = { 23, 31, 7, 15, 23, 31, 7, 15, 23, 31, 7, 15, 23, 31, 7, 15, 23, 31, 7, 15, 23, 31, 7, 15 }
Tr5 = { 8, 16, 24, 0, 8, 16, 24, 0, 8, 16, 24, 0, 8, 16, 24, 0, 8, 16, 24, 0, 8, 16, 24, 0 }
Tr6 = { 25, 1, 9, 17, 25, 1, 9, 17, 25, 1, 9, 17, 25, 1, 9, 17, 25, 1, 9, 17, 25, 1, 9, 17 }
Tr7 = { 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2, 10, 18, 26, 2 }
```

..and `Tm` (in hex):

```
Tm0 = { 5a827999, d151d6a1, 482133a9, bef090b1, 35bfedb9, ac8f4ac1, 235ea7c9, 9a2e04d1, 10fd61d9, 87ccbee1, fe9c1be9, 756b78f1, ec3ad5f9, 630a3301, d9d99009, 50a8ed11, c7784a19, 3e47a721, b5170429, 2be66131, a2b5be39, 19851b41, 90547849, 723d551 }
Tm1 = { c95c653a, 402bc242, b6fb1f4a, 2dca7c52, a499d95a, 1b693662, 9238936a, 907f072, 7fd74d7a, f6a6aa82, 6d76078a, e4456492, 5b14c19a, d1e41ea2, 48b37baa, bf82d8b2, 365235ba, ad2192c2, 23f0efca, 9ac04cd2, 118fa9da, 885f06e2, ff2e63ea, 75fdc0f2 }
Tm2 = { 383650db, af05ade3, 25d50aeb, 9ca467f3, 1373c4fb, 8a432203, 1127f0b, 77e1dc13, eeb1391b, 65809623, dc4ff32b, 531f5033, c9eead3b, 40be0a43, b78d674b, 2e5cc453, a52c215b, 1bfb7e63, 92cadb6b, 99a3873, 8069957b, f738f283, 6e084f8b, e4d7ac93 }
Tm3 = { a7103c7c, 1ddf9984, 94aef68c, b7e5394, 824db09c, f91d0da4, 6fec6aac, e6bbc7b4, 5d8b24bc, d45a81c4, 4b29decc, c1f93bd4, 38c898dc, af97f5e4, 266752ec, 9d36aff4, 14060cfc, 8ad56a04, 1a4c70c, 78742414, ef43811c, 6612de24, dce23b2c, 53b19834 }
Tm4 = { 15ea281d, 8cb98525, 388e22d, 7a583f35, f1279c3d, 67f6f945, dec6564d, 5595b355, cc65105d, 43346d65, ba03ca6d, 30d32775, a7a2847d, 1e71e185, 95413e8d, c109b95, 82dff89d, f9af55a5, 707eb2ad, e74e0fb5, 5e1d6cbd, d4ecc9c5, 4bbc26cd, c28b83d5 }
Tm5 = { 84c413be, fb9370c6, 7262cdce, e9322ad6, 600187de, d6d0e4e6, 4da041ee, c46f9ef6, 3b3efbfe, b20e5906, 28ddb60e, 9fad1316, 167c701e, 8d4bcd26, 41b2a2e, 7aea8736, f1b9e43e, 68894146, df589e4e, 5627fb56, ccf7585e, 43c6b566, ba96126e, 31656f76 }
Tm6 = { f39dff5f, 6a6d5c67, e13cb96f, 580c1677, cedb737f, 45aad087, bc7a2d8f, 33498a97, aa18e79f, 20e844a7, 97b7a1af, e86feb7, 85565bbf, fc25b8c7, 72f515cf, e9c472d7, 6093cfdf, d7632ce7, 4e3289ef, c501e6f7, 3bd143ff, b2a0a107, 296ffe0f, a03f5b17 }
Tm7 = { 6277eb00, d9474808, 5016a510, c6e60218, 3db55f20, b484bc28, 2b541930, a2237638, 18f2d340, 8fc23048, 6918d50, 7d60ea58, f4304760, 6affa468, e1cf0170, 589e5e78, cf6dbb80, 463d1888, bd0c7590, 33dbd298, aaab2fa0, 217a8ca8, 9849e9b0, f1946b8 }
```

(I'm not sure why they didn't just include these as tables in the spec).

Comment: thanks! i knew i was doing something wrong. can you make Tm as well?

Comment: me neither. those real crypto people can be really annoying at times. sigh. i still dont know why i cant get these values. i'll try again tomorrow